# Convert AngularJS service to Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular

How to convert this AngularJS to Angular? 
I created component named `ForgotPassword` and have no idea how to correctly send `http.post` to my c# controller.

```
function (window, angular) {
"use strict";

angular.module("Mobile")
.service("accountService", ["$http", function ($http) {
 return {

forgotPassword: function (email, success, error) {
$http.post("Account/ForgotPassword", { Email: email}).success(success).error(error);
   }
  }
 }]);
})(window, window.angular);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a service class

app.serivce.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AppProvider {    
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  public forgotPassword(email: string):Observable<any> {
    let url:string = 'apiUrl/Account/ForgotPassword';
    let body: any = { Email: email }

    return this.http.post(url, body).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

This method would be called from inside your component.ts file

Comment: Do you mean, that i don't have to create separated app.service file?

Comment: @V.Aliosha yes, you should.

Answer (score 1):

Create a service class

```
﻿import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class accountService {

  forgotPassword(param): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('Account/ForgotPassword',
            JSON.stringify(param),
            {headers: this.headers})
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

then import service into component

```
import {accountService}  '../../services/accountService '
```

call your service from component

```
export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit  {
     constructor(private http: HttpClient , public httpService: accountService) {


    forgotPassword() {
        this.busy =   this.httpService.forgotPassword()
            .subscribe(
                data => { Email:this.email }, 
                error => console.log('error'),
                () => this.forgotPasswordComplete(null)

            );
    }

    forgotPasswordComplete(result: any) {
        //alert('error loading http service');
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

accountComponent.ts

```
constructor(private accountSer: accountService)

forgotPasswordButton(){
this.accountSer.forgotPassword(value)
}
```

accountService.ts

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';


import 'rxjs/Rx';



@Injectable()
export class UserDetailService {
    public headers: Headers;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    forgotPassword(value){
    this.http.post('Account/ForgotPassword', JSON.stringify(value), { headers: this.headers }).subscribe();}}
```

Comment: how can I do this `private http: Http` in es6?

Comment: You can't. ": Http" is typescript typing. static types are not a feature in es6

Comment: So, is there a way to do this without TS?